# How do i create a custom model binder in ASP.NET Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, custom-model-binder

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms and can't migrate to ASP.NET MVC right now. I love the way the MVC team implemented a custom IHttpHandler, or HttpModule (Not sure which one) that gets the JSON data passed in from an Client Side Ajax request and passes the data into the action method on the requested page.

I want to be able to intercept a Http Request, retrieve that JSON/"Query String Parameters", and call a method on the page while passing the retrieved data as it's parameter.

Currently, i've implemented a custom route and it works fine. The only part that is missing for me is the "Custom Model Binder" as the call it in ASP.NET MVC.

Please can someone help me with a clue as to how i can go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [ASP.NET MVVM](http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/)?

ASP.NET MVVM provides a framework to implement the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, a.k.a. the Presentation Model pattern in ASP.NET projects. Developers can take advantages of Dependency Injection and Event Broker to write concise, elegant and business focused code.

The ASP.NET MVVM offers the following benefits:

- Leverage ASP.NET functions, such as web form, user control and data
  binding
- Achieve a clear separation of concerns
- Facilitate test driven development (TDD)
- Write and maintain simpler code using the attribute annotations